# Get facebook fan count from the graph objet in new SDK PHP v4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the fan count of a facebook page with the graph objet in new SDK PHP v4?
$user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

I assume authentication is not needed for this information, right?

Answer (score 0):

See the `likes` field of the `page` object:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading

Comment: But, that information is public, right? So I dont need a user login into facebook... but then how can I do the facebook request with no session?  //
     
      $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/masymejorcom' ) )->execute();

      // Get response as an array
      $user = $request->getGraphObject();
      
      $fans = $user['likes']

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say. Use the standard app access token via `$session = new FacebookSession('access token here');` as outlined at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication